# Passing variable from PHP to Python on Windows 10 affected by import pandas

Tags: php, python, pandas, debugging

I am trying to pass a variable from PHP to Python on Windows, but the line "import pandas" is causing an issue. All my code below is bare-bones of the actual process I am trying to create for simplicity. The first chunk of code is my Index, the second is the PHP code called by Index.php, and the last chunk is Python.

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<b>Enter a folder path </b> 
</head>
<body>
<form action="BlastParse.php" method="post">
    Path: <input type ="text" name="path"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

BlastParse.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 

#getting path passed from index.php
$masterpath = $_POST["path"];

echo 'The path requested to be passed is: ' . $masterpath . '<br>';

#my directories 
$python = 'C:/Users/Garrett/Anaconda3/python.exe';
$pyscript = 'C:/Users/Garrett/Documents/Python/temp.py';
$pyscriptPrimed = $pyscript . ' ';
#creating the command
$command ="$python $pyscriptPrimed";

#executing the command to call temp.py; adding passed path to command
exec($command .$masterpath, $output, $return_var);

 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

temp.py

```
import os
import sys

#path passed into python from php
file_path = sys.argv[1]

#file_path = 'Write this string to file'

with open("C:/Users/Garrett/Documents/Python/copy.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(file_path)
#PROBLEM HERE
import pandas as pd

with open("C:/Users/Garrett/Documents/Python/copy2.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(file_path)
```

I am using the writing to copy.txt and copy2.txt for debugging purposes roughly since there isn't anything produced on the terminal. When I comment out the import pandas line, the copy2.txt file is created and written to properly. If not, the copy2.txt file is not created and the $return_var variable returns a 1 in PHP (which I'm not sure what the error code represents yet).

I am running on Windows 10 with Python 3.7, and using VS Code through Anaconda.

Comment: So, it *looks* like `pandas` is failing to import. Likely do to path issues. Not an expert on php `exec`, but if I had to guess, that would be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood this is because pandas is not installed where you are trying to run. This could be because you have not activated your anaconda environment before you are calling your python script.

I haven't tested the code below but it should point you in the right direction:

```
$command ="source activate environment-name && $python $pyscriptPrimed && source deactivate";'
```

In order to help debug this the first thing I'd try is wrapping the import statement in a try catch and either printing:

```
try:
    import pandas as pd
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

If that fails to print to console try this to write to file:

```
try:
    import pandas as pd
except Exception as e:
    with open("C:/Users/Garrett/Documents/Python/error.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(e))
```

Just as an aside on your comment in the question error code 1 from a script is a Catchall for general errors. An exit status of 0 is a success

Comment: Thanks so much! I added the try except and it spit out that I needed to also import numpy....so I did. It then spit out that "Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy." I then uninstalled numpy, reinstalled, and it worked!